# Returning value from Threads in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I wanted to add two values and return them from the thread however I get the following error. My code is

```
main.c: In function ‘sum_thread’:
main.c:19:18: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   19 |     pthread_exit((void *)sum);
      |
```

I was expecting the thread would return the sum and to print them. I want to be able to use the output of sum in main after a thread returns the value.
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int global[2];

void *sum_thread(void *arg)
{
    int n1,n2,sum;
    n1=global[0];
    n2=global[1];
    sum = n1+n2;

    printf("N1 + N2 = %d\n",sum);

    pthread_exit((void *)sum);
}

int main() 
{   
    void *status =0;
    printf("First number: ");
    scanf("%d",&global[0]);

    printf("Second number: ");
    scanf("%d",&global[1]);

    pthread_t tid_sum;
    pthread_create(&tid_sum,NULL,sum_thread,global);
    pthread_join(tid_sum,(void *)&status);

    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: That's a *warning*, not an error.  It's telling you that there's something suspicious about your program (which there is), but that does not prevent compilation from continuing to completion.

Comment: Using `(void*)(intptr_t)sum` would silence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler issues this warning whenever the value of an integer is converted to a pointer. As pointed out by @ikegami in a comment, you can fix it using a cast :

```
pthread_exit((void *)(intptr_t)sum);
```

and casting again in `main`:

```
printf("%d\n", (int)(intptr_t)status);
```

Don't forget to `#include <stdint.h>`

But if performance is not critical at this point, consider using dynamic memory:

```
int *sum = malloc(sizeof(int));

...
*sum = n1+n2;
printf("N1 + N2 = %d\n", *sum);
pthread_exit(sum);
```

and in `main`:

```
pthread_join(tid_sum, &status);
printf("%d\n", *(int *)status);
free(status);
```

This has the advantage that you are not limited to integer types and is easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly fine now. I forgot about local and dynamic memory literally!